# Understanding JSP errorPage attribute

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I setup a simple test to see how <%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %> behaves. It seems to execute the said page "error.jsp" when I throw an exception, but if I test syntax errors like missing a ";", I am still getting the tomcat error page. Am I missing something or shouldnt this execute the error page on any type of error?

Comment: Please, for the love of god, use Java scriptlets sparingly. I'm currently working on a project where JSP scriplets, JSP, JSTL, and JavaScript are all interspersed. It's a nightmare to maintain code littered with scriptlets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSP error page is only for run-time errors (when the page is loaded), the tomcat errors are compile errors when the servlet container tries to compile your JSP.